# "Локон страсти"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "локон страсти"?

Answer (score 1):

Достоверного объяснения я не знаю, могу только предположить, что виной всему давнишнее женское убеждение, что специальный завиток прически притягивает противоположный пол.
Но само выражение, насколько могу судить, сравнительно недавнее.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, выражение пошло от обычая дарить возлюбленному на память локон своих волос.